# Cloud Run for Anthos: Configuration "<DEPLOY-NAME>" does not have any ready Revision

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-run, google-anthos

I've been running an app in managed Cloud Run for months, and thought I'd try getting it up and running on GKE / Anthos. Followed the [setup guide](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/gke/setup) with little trouble. I'm stuck, now, though. The following error occurs on my standard image as well as one I made with modifications to ensure all the logging went to `/dev/stdout` thanks to suggestions found [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59107010/gcloud-cloud-run-deployment-fails-for-deployment-to-gke). Am I missing something obvious?

Note that Kube shows no running pods and the logs are empty.

```
Deploying container to Cloud Run for Anthos service [DEPLOY-NAME] in namespace [cloudrun] of cluster [CLUSTER-NAME]
Deploying...
Creating Revision................interrupted
Deployment failed
ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) Configuration "DEPLOY-NAME" does not have any ready Revision.
```

Comment: Is the container image URL valid? Seems like that could be one cause of this message: https://github.com/knative/serving/issues/1614

Comment: The "interrupted" is a sign of something going wrong. (Are you canceling things mid-deployment?) Can you deploy via Cloud Console and see if there are any more visible errors there?

Comment: I just tested by deploying via the Cloud Run UI, using the default `gcr.io/cloudrun/hello` image on a brand new cluster. Same error.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Though nothing will stop you from doing it, Cloud Run for Anthos requires at least an `n1-standard-2` node - a minimum of 2 vCPUs.